# How to access instance variable from a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I've defined an instance variable in my `ApplicationController` like that:

```
@team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
```

Now, in my `EventsCreator` model I'd like to access `@team` from above:

```
class EventsCreator
  # ...

  def team_name
    name = @team.name
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

With that code I get the following error:

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

How should I access instance variables like this from a model? Is there a better way or better practice to do so?

---

**Edit 1:**

The `event.rb` model is the model which contains common information which is also saved in the database:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  attr_accessor :comment
  ...
end
```

The `events_creator.rb` model is kind of an extension to `event.rb`. It contains some logic e.g. for repeating events:

```
class EventsCreator
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :beginning, :ending, :repeat_frequency, :repeat_until_date
  ...
end
```

`EventsCreator` does not directly create Records in the DB. It just does some logic and saves the data through `Event` model.

Now without having a direct relation to `team.rb` I want to be able to access the instance variable `@team` which is defined in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base
  before_action :set_team_for_nested

  private
  def set_team_for_nested
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
  end
end
```

My `routes.rb` file is nesting all routes inside `team` because I need the `team_id` for every action:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :teams do
    resources :events
    get '/events_creator', to: 'events_creator#new', as: 'new_events_creator'
    post '/events_creator', to: 'events_creator#create', as: 'create_events_creator'
  end
end
```

Now I have no idea how to access the `@team` instance variable (which I thought is defined for the whole application) from a model. Since I'm quite new to Rails, I might have messed up things, please tell me if there are better ways to achieve the same.

Comment: You can, for example, pass it in the initializer of EventCreator. `event_creator = EventCreator.new(@team)`

Comment: I deleted my answer since it does not fit to your problem. I would suggest now the same as @patkoperwas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass the `team` as an argument to your class.

```
class EventsCreator
  attr_reader :team
  def initialize(team)
    @team = team
  end

  def some_method
    puts team.name
  end
end

# Then in your controller you can do this
def create
  EventsCreator.new(@team)
end
```

If you plan on including `ActiveModel::Model` then you can just do

```
class EventsCreator
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :team

  def some_method
    puts team.name
  end
end

# And then in your controller it's the same thing
def create
  EventsCreator.new(@team)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

simple

```
class EventCreator

  ...

  def team_name
    name #will return name of class instance
    #or do something with it
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is an answer and since your *explanation* is "simple" I think you have made it anything but

Comment: (s)he wants to access an instance property and i've tried to show how to do. what's wrong? -))

Comment: You simply showed how to call another (undefined) method and/or state a nonexistent local variable. You have no explanation and certainly no instance variables. This in way addresses that actually question

Comment: you are commenting based on an anachronism. i've posted when question was like that - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9dbd5cd7-4c80-428f-9298-4e0805825d73/view-source

just realised that it's been edited and evolved to a completely different question.